# call actionscript from mxml?

Tags: actionscript

i thought of drawing the interface using mxml markup. When the user clicks on a button it should call a specific method in a .as file. How can i do that in mxml ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var class1:AcClass = new AcClass();
```

then

```
   class1.NameOfMethod();
```

first instantiate action script class then call its method as above. hope it helps.

Comment: ACClass is the name of you class in .as

Comment: How to destroy the instantiated class, I have a class I instantiat it first after my operation I want to destroy it so that next time I instantiate it should not create problem with Static variables.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this article](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=764091) helpful. Basically, you use the `<mx:Script>` tag to include a script, and then you can set an ActionScript function as the function to execute in response to the button press.

From [another article on Adobe's website](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_6.html) there is a very simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- usingas/ASScriptBlock.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    public function calculate():void {
        var n:Number = Number(fahrenheit.text);
        var t:Number = Math.round((n-32)/1.8*10)/10;
        celsius.text=String(t);
    }
]]></mx:Script>

<mx:Panel title="My Application" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10"
 paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">
  <mx:HBox>
     <mx:Label text="Temperature in Fahrenheit:"/>
     <mx:TextInput id="fahrenheit" width="120"/>
     <mx:Button label="Convert" click="calculate();" />
     <mx:Label text="Temperature in Celsius:"/>
     <mx:Label id="celsius" width="120" fontSize="24"/>
    </mx:HBox>
  </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a .as class, and in your mxml file (inside the Script tag) create an instance of the .as class. Then use instanceName.functionName() to call the function. Thats the basic OOP method of doing it. Or use the code-behind pattern